# how to use AppSettings of app.config in itself

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config, appsettings

I have a wcf config in client side. I need use a key in AppSettings by `ServerIP` Name for other sections in App.Config instead of `localhost`, Because count of my endpoints is many and my server ip is variable. How can I it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ServerIP" value="localhost"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        ...
    </bindings>
    <client>

      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9000/WcfServices/Person/PersonService" 
        binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RCISPNetTcpBindingWpf"
        contract="Common.ServiceContract.IPersonService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IPersonService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" /> <!--How use ServerIP in appSettings instead of localhost-->
        </identity>
      </endpoint>           

    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can not do that, but you might be able to use [web.config transformations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx) if you are using VisualStudio 2010. I think you have to use web deploy, or run an MSBuild task yourself to run the transforms.

Answer (score 0):

you could not use appsettings in app.config itself.
you have two possibilities:
-use appsettings by code like making your our custom  section
http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/12/custom-configuration-sections-in-3-easy-steps.aspx
-use a nant build or msbuild with a placeholder
[How to use MSbuild property in TransformXml task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958646/how-to-use-msbuild-property-in-transformxml-task)